# How to update the whole app due to specific event?

Tags: reactjs

I build a 3D product configurator and a problem appeared. I am pretty new to React wherefore I can't figure out how to solve it.

My app structure is as follows:

```
App.js
- Scene3D
- Options
    - Scene3D
- CheckoutBar
```

All changes can be made by the user by clicking different buttons in the option section. One of them is to change the product model. Each product model provides different options. All options are stored in an object in App.js.

My thought was to create an event "change-model" which triggers the render function of App.js again with the choosen model. Unfortunately this doesn't work. The option section won't be updated. The new option data won't get passed to all component underlying App.js.

How is it possible to solve that?

I appreciate your help. Thank you!

**App.js**

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    configurations: {
      standard: require('./configurations/standard.json'),
      second: require('./configurations/standard.json'),
      third: require('./configurations/third.json')
    }
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('change-model', this.render)
  this.loadScripts()
}

render = e => {
  return (
    <div className="proconf">
      <Scene3d defaultConfig={this.getDefaultConfig()} />               
      <Controls configuration={this.state.configurations[e && e.detail.model ? e.detail.model : "standard"]} />
      <CheckoutBar defaultConfig={this.getDefaultConfig()} prices={this.getPrices()} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Controls.js**

```js
emitModelChangeEvent(modelName) {
  let event = new CustomEvent('change-model', { detail: {
    model: modelName
  }})
  window.dispatchEvent(event)
}

createOptions = (options) => {
  let optionStorage = []
  for (var x in options) {
    this.emitModelChangeEvent(value)
    this.setState(prev => ({
      productConfig: {
        ...prev.productConfig,
        model: value
      }
    }))
    
    let buttonStorage = []
    for (var y in options[x].values) {
      buttonStorage.push(<div onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); emitChangeEvent(this, valueKey) }}>{valueInfo}</div>)
    }
    optionStorage.push(<div>{buttonStorage}</div>)
    
  return optionStorage
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button>
        {this.props.stepName}
      </button>
      <div>
          {this.createOptions(this.props.options)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: "My thought was to create an event "change-model"", is this an event from calling `addEventListener` on a DOM? Also, can you show us some code to have more context.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Thank you xadm. Lifting state up solved it!!!